# How to avoid your onion host privatekey to be stolen?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, web-hosting, private, private-key

i want to move my onion hosting from my local ubuntu 16 server to an hosting service one. My only concern is: how can i keep my domain generating privatekey totally safe? I've spent 12 days to generate my unique onion address and i really don't want to lose it.

Is there any way to encrypt them, lock them or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Run tor

**2.** Encrypt key:

**`openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -pbkdf2 -in /var/lib/tor/example.onion/hs_ed25519_secret_key > /var/lib/tor/example.onion/hs_ed25519_secret_key`**

**3.** Profit

**P.S.** To restart again you need to stop tor daemon, decrypt your key:

**`openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -pbkdf2 -in /var/lib/tor/example.onion/hs_ed25519_secret_key > /var/lib/tor/example.onion/hs_ed25519_secret_key`**

and repeat **1**, **2** steps

Comment: I gotta decrypt/encrypt every time i restart tor, correct? I'm basically keeping my key there but password protected right?

Comment: @FrancescoRubino yes, the above command (step **2**) just takes original file "hs_ed25519_secret_key" and overwrites the content with AES encryption using a passphrase (you can use one more option '-a' it encode your binary secret key in _readable_ base64 after encryption). Btw, you can "cat" secret key after running openssl command, and you will see your encrypted key. Tor does not need a secret key **after** you start daemon , so you can encrypt it and decrypt when you need to restart and encrypt again. I mean, you know, right? :D (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I used gpg, is it good enough too? any advice on securing the webserver and the server itself?

Comment: @FrancescoRubino well, public key encryption (gpg) is unnecessary in this case, rly. Better to use the above openssl examples (for example, write a simple bash script). About security advices... The main thing is isolate tor from the _outside_ and don't use shitty apache only nginx with unix sockets. I not really trust the containers so I prefer to use virtualization (kvm) on dedi, but it depends on which project you run, you know :D First tweak your torrc. For example, use "Sandbox 1, SocksPort 0 (Disabling client side... I mean, why do you need it for hidden service, right? :D)" etc. **P1**

Comment: @FrancescoRubino Read about all stuff in the docs [tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html). Little example of tor/nginx configs if I remember it right :D **`SocksPort 0 Sandbox 1 HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/example.onion/ HiddenServicePort 80 unix:/var/run/example-80.sock HiddenServiceVersion 3`** then in "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" in **server{}** block add **`listen unix:/var/run/example-80.sock default_server; server_name example.onion; allow unix:; deny all;  server_tokens off;`** **P2**

Comment: @FrancescoRubino Possible more, but I am limited by the number of characters and poor text formatting... So, that's all.

Comment: @FrancescoRubino Ah and one more thing, if you use unix sockets if i'm remember right (if not maybe someone to correct me) you can edit "nano /lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service" and add "PrivateNetwork=yes" option.

Comment: Good suggestion, tnx. Well, it's basically a 2 part website. 1 A diary about some governament stuffs i know about+some readers tips and 2 a ftp server where trusted users can anon upload documents.

Comment: My fear in not in the diary part (No way to hack a text only page right?) but about the ftp one. ftp could be a huge risk, but i need something like ftp, sftp, etc... where users can send files (not download or see) via cli.

Comment: Usually files are few kb txt

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is currently no way to avoid that your key, at least for a short time, is on your server in cleartext.

However, the [next generation onion services (V3)](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/NextGenOnions) will allow you to do that once ticket [#18098 (offline keys)](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/18098) has been implemented. Beware that the addresses differ from V2 addresses and you'll have to create a new onion address.

Comment: No way to implement it for now?

Comment: Well, it's actaully already in the stable version. I just enabled it and now i have my onionv3 address. Now... how can i make the key secure? How do i have to split private and public key?

Comment: @FrancescoRubino, yes, v3 is in stable. However, you can't keep the key off your machine until v3 support has been extended to support offline keys (ticket #18098).